# How to map several keys in Vim

Tags: vim, macvim

How would I map `ctrl+w+o` to execute `:Bonly<CR>`?

I have tried

```
unmap <C-W>o
map <C-W>o :Bonly<CR>
```

Save file and source it with `so %`, but does not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your mapping (the `:unmap` is not necessary) should work with a sequence of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, followed by <kbd>o</kbd>.

If you want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, that'd be `<C-w><C-o>`.

In Vim, one can only map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd> / <kbd>Alt</kbd> combinations (and not all of them, unfortunately!) with a single key (like <kbd>W</kbd>). But there's a plugin that may help you achieve a mapping of all keys pressed simultaneously: [arpeggio - Key mappings for simultaneously pressed keys](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2425)

Comment: Does the sequence would be `<C-W>o` as I have?. Just to know, how do you write the keys to be displayed like that?

Comment: I think I don't need simultaneous keys, do I? It is ctrl then w then o, with ctrl pressed

Comment: If you want ctrl-w then ctrl-o then you need to type `<C-w><C-o>`.  Case may matter.